# Strange loading css/js issue

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am working on a site that when going to the URL on desktop it seems like the content is loading first then the styles about a 1 second late that creates a kind of 'flashing' effect on each page,

The sections expand and then the background images are loaded next,

I am using the WPRocket plugin - does anybody know what the cause of this is likely to be?

I am not sure if I am allowed to include the domain,

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a case of Flash of unstyled content,
[Wikipedia has a good breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way of fixing this without having access to  the development files? I believe it was a elementor site made on Wix and transferred to a regular hosting site

Comment: I imagine the website under its current domain is likely still pointing to stylesheets and the like that are located on servers at the previous host ?

Comment: ah thanks for this! Not sure it is something I can solve but thank you for the help - I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'd recommend opening the developer tools in your webbrowser (In most webbrowsers: press F12 while you're looking at your site -> Network tab -> Press CTRL F5 to reload the page), you should then see a list being formed of every resource the current page imported. You can ignore the ones that are located on your own domain, the problem is likely the ones that are loaded from external domains; once you know which files those are, you can dive deeper into how easy or dodgy it is to place (and refer to) those files locally.